# How to delete a space before and after symbol using regex

Tags: python, regex

As an example, I have a string containing complex numbers with different formatting. I want to delete redundant spaces around "+" but save the spaces between the numbers, so I can convert it then into a list.

I've tried this without any expectations and it doesn't work.

```
data_str = "15+i10 15+ i10 15 +i10 15 + i10"
data_str = re.sub("\+(?= )", "", data_str)
```

Desired result is `"15+i10 15+i10 15+i10 15+i10"`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace any number of spaces around the symbol with nothing i.e.

```
data_str = "15+i10 15+ i10 15 +i10 15 + i10"
data_str = re.sub("\s*\+\s*", "+", data_str)
```